# How to load a class file from filesystem and use it in the classPool?

Tags: java, ioexception, javassist

I am using javassist to modify classes of an existing jarfile and write those classes back after modifying. This all works fine, but now I want to load a class file from the program currently running into the classPool:

```java
ClassPool classPool = new ClassPool();
ClassPath classPath = classPool.appendClassPath(jarFilePath);

// here I want to insert a class from my current program into the classPool (IOException here)
classPool.makeClass(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().openConnection().getInputStream());

// ...
```

The problem is, that I get an exception when calling the makeClass method:

> java.io.IOException: bad magic number: 6xxxxxx
>
> at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:790)
>
> at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.(ClassFile.java:185)
>
> at javassist.CtClassType.(CtClassType.java:98)
>
> at javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:707)
>
> at javassist.ClassPool.makeClass(ClassPool.java:685)
>
> ...

I know that magic number in this case refers to the `CAFEBABE` that marks class files: https://www.javainterviewpoint.com/magic-number-in-java/

How do I fix this problem so I can use this class from my program in the classPool?

Comment: I would print out the URL returned by method `getLocation()` to see what the actual file is.

Comment: @Abra inspecting the location, I found, that the getLocation returns the url to the folder of the packages and not the location of the class file. Manually appending the package and class name solved it, Thx

Comment: Maybe you should [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?